# Vue Router: infinite redirection

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using Vue 3 and Vue Router4.0.

I want to build a routing system with authentication and authorizations. In my "router.js" file , I wrote:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/home",
    component: Home,
    meta: { requiresAuth: false }
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    component: Login,
    meta: { requiresAuth: false }
  },
.....
```

and I added the "beforeEach" like the documentation explained :

```
router.beforeEach(async(to) => {
  //todo : get the store here 
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user') == null ? false : true;
  const roleId = user ? user.role_id : 'UNKNOWN';
  const authorizedRoles = to.meta.authorizedRoles ? Array.from(to.meta.authorizedRoles) : [];
  
  // no authentication required
  if (!to.meta.requireAuth) {
    console.log('no authorization required')
    return { path: to.fullPath}
  }
....
```

when I am going to the route "/login", I have the message:

> [Vue Router warn]: Detected an infinite redirection in a navigation guard when going from "/" to "/login".

I am learning Vue and Vue Router and I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: You've a typo in `to.meta.requireAuth`, you're missing the `s` in require

Comment: thanks for the comment but it is not the origin of the problem. I don't understant what happen. I see the message 'no authorization required' in the console. But there is no redirection. And still the message "infinite redirection"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return { path: to.fullPath}` results in a redirect to the same route and causes infinite redirect.

It should be:

```
return true
```

Comment: thanks , it works fine now, i spent so many hours on this !

Answer (score 2):

I like to use router guard like this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth) && !userIsAuthenticated)
     next({name: "Login"});
  else
     next()
    
});
```